# Inbox view disappears from recent app list at the drop of a hat

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, global-inbox

Not sure what the proper terminology is for this, but... There are two different appearances for the inbox in the Stack Exchange app. There's the one you can get to by clicking the counter in the top bar:

*Clicking this...* [image: inbox counter]

*Brings you to this...* [image: normal inbox]

And then there's the other one, which seems to only show up if you tap a notification in the system notification pull-down *and* the app isn't already running:

[image: inbox app]

Note that there's nothing to it *but* the inbox - you can't any other part of the app. It's almost as though it's a separate inbox app... An impression that's strengthened when tapping one of the messages pops the splashscreen before finally taking you into the main app. This isn't the bug I'm reporting though; maybe it's intentional, and if nothing else it's really not too annoying...

But what *is* frustrating is the fact that you can't get *back* to the "inbox app" if you leave it. Not a big deal, if you're leaving it for the main app since you can always get to the inbox there - but if you're leaving it to jump into a browser (say, because you tapped a chat notification) or answer a phone call, or even just opening up the app switcher (where it *does* appear, initially)... It disappears without a trace. The "back" button takes you to the desktop, and the app disappears from the "recent apps" list.

Not a big deal when there's only one new message, but pretty annoying when there are several.

Comment: Oh no, Shog. Android has sucked you in too? :-)

Comment: They stopped selling hardware for WebOS. What else can I do?

Comment: Well, duh. http://www.ebay.com/bhp/apple-newton

Comment: Thanks for reporting this! We'- wait a minute...

Comment: but yeah a whole re-work of this system has been in talks for a while, we're still trying to figure out the correct way to handle it but it's planned to change.

Comment: Cool. I'll be patient; took me this long to figure out I wasn't crazy, can live with it a while longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I killed that "full inbox view" a while back, all inbox operations in the app are now handled out of the right-side drawer visible in almost every single view of the application.